# Unauthorized: 401 Azure Media Service in PHP. How do I connect to Azure Media Service through PHP

Tags: php, azure, http-status-code-401, azure-media-services, unauthorized

I am trying to connect to `Azure Media Service` through `PHP SDK` provided by Azure on github. The userconfig.php has few params, I gave all my credentials but I'm getting

> "Fatal error: Uncaught WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException: Fail:
>   Code: 401"

```
<?php

set_time_limit(600); //set timeout to 10 minutes, or you can set max_execution_time in php.ini

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$tenant =  "******.onmicrosoft.com";
$username = '***@*****.com';
$password = '****@12345';
$clientId = "*******-*******-46e9-b525-5f1f2ec4e4ea";
$clientKey = "*******-*******/uUS+hKm67kfwZZs4w4=";
$restApiEndpoint = "https://indwaretest1.restv2.japanwest.media.azure.net/api/";
// $pfxFileName = "C:\\Path\\To\\keystore.pfx";
// $pfxPassword = "KeyStorePassword";
```

I'm getting this error..

```
$ php index.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException: Fail:
Code: 401
Value: Unauthorized
details (if any): . in D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php:405
Stack trace:
#0 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php(301): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient::throwIfError(401, 'Unauthorized', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream), Array)
#1 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\RestProxy.php(144): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient->sendAndGetHttpResponse(Array, Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\Url))
#2 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy.php(89): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\RestProxy->sendHttpContext(Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpCallContext))
#3 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy.php(128): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy->sendHttpContext(Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal in D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php on line 405

Fatal error: Uncaught WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException: Fail:
Code: 401
Value: Unauthorized
details (if any): . in D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php:405
Stack trace:
#0 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php(301): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient::throwIfError(401, 'Unauthorized', Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream), Array)
#1 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\RestProxy.php(144): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient->sendAndGetHttpResponse(Array, Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\Url))
#2 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy.php(89): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\RestProxy->sendHttpContext(Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpCallContext))
#3 D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy.php(128): WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy->sendHttpContext(Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal in D:\PHP\azure\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\src\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php on line 405
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, I suppose you have not given a role to your service principal for the media service.

To fix the issue, navigate to the media service in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add role assignment` -> select your service principal(just search the `clientId` ) and give the `Contributor` or `Owner` role -> `Save`, then it should work.

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-use-aad-auth-to-access-ams-api#access-control).

Comment: I did everything. I don't understand what seems to be the problem here. Good thing is, when I tried to connect with the clientId and the clientKey, I got access. But it's not working with username and passwword.